# $httpBackend mock not sending a request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, httpbackend

After too many hours, I cannot for the life of me get this example working.  I'm following Ben Lesh's [excellent guides](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html) to mocking `$http` requests in Angular, but for some reason the service request is not sending.

I have verified that the service is working properly by building a separate HTML DOM and applying my app and a tiny controller to it.  I'm using Jasmine 1.3 and Angular 1.2.9 (and `angular-mocks.js` of course).

Here's the app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('httpBasedService', function($http) {
    return {
        sendMessage: function(msg) {
            return $http.get('something.json?msg=' + msg)
                .then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result.data)
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

And the test:

```
describe("httpBasedService ", function () {
   var httpBasedService,
        mockBackend;

    beforeEach(function (){
        module('myApp');

        inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _httpBasedService_) {
            mockBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            httpBasedService = _httpBasedService_;
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should send the msg and return the response.', function () {
        var returnData = {excited: true};
        mockBackend.expectGET('something.json?msg=wee').respond(returnData);

        var returnedPromise = httpBasedService.sendMessage('wee');
        var result;

        returnedPromise.then(function(response) {
            result = response;
        });

        mockBackend.flush();
        expect(result).toEqual(returnData);
    });
});
```

I'm getting a `Error: No pending request to flush !` and of course a `Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET` (since nothing has been sent). I watch the network requests and sure enough, no request is sent, even if I remove the mock backend.

I've commented out stuff, restructured stuff, tried lots of other examples, but to no avail.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, when I [talk to the duck](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/), the problem is fixed.

Turns out I was using `angular-mocks.js` from v1.1.0.  My `angular.js` version was 1.2.9.

Facepalm.

Check your versions, future readers, and save yourself a few hours.

Comment: Hehe.. I was like.. "wtf is going on here? That really should work.. maybe $http.get is prepending a leading / or some such".. I think this sort of versioning-thing gets us all at some point or other.